# Tooltip as PrimeFaces component

Tags: primefaces

I tried to have a modified tooltip component (basically to group some common properties), but I'm not able to show the tooltip as I do not know how to define `for` attribute.

As a MCVE I have this page

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:comp="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/comp" >

<h:head>
    <title>Component Test</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <h:form>
        <comp:myInputText value="ABC" />
    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

where `comp:` prefix is for custom components (in META-INF/resources/comp folder)

When my component is defined as:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:comp="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/comp">

<c:interface>
    <c:attribute name="value" required="true" />
</c:interface>

<c:implementation>
    <p:inputText id="text" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" />
    <p:tooltip for="@previous" value="tooltip" />
</c:implementation>
</html>
```

everything is ok, so in next step I tried replace p:tooltip with `comp:myTooltip`, but it is not shown

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:comp="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/comp">

<c:interface>
    <c:attribute name="value" required="true" />
</c:interface>

<c:implementation>
    <p:inputText id="text" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" />
    <comp:myTooltip forr="@previous" data="tooltip" />
</c:implementation>
</html>
```

Problem seems to me, that I'm not able to define for properly (I had to rename for to forr, just because for cannot be used).

I'm getting error:

> Cannot find component for expression "@previous" referenced from "j_idt5:j_idt12:j_idt14:j_idt11".

I tried also to define id for inputText and use it in comp:myTooltip, it didn't work too...

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:comp="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/comp">

<c:interface>
    <c:attribute name="value" required="true" />
</c:interface>

<c:implementation>
    <p:inputText id="text" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" />
    <comp:myTooltip forr="text" data="tooltip" />
</c:implementation>
</html>
```

> Cannot find component for expression "text" referenced from "j_idt5:j_idt12:j_idt14:j_idt11".

**edit (forgotten `comp:myTooltip`):**

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<c:interface>
    <c:attribute name="forr" required="true" />
    <c:attribute name="data" required="true" />
</c:interface>

<c:implementation>
    <p:tooltip for="#{cc.attrs.forr}" position="right" value="#{cc.attrs.data}" />
</c:implementation>
</html>
```

Comment: You didn't paste your composite component for you comp:tooltip.  I would like to see that here as well.

Comment: And make sure your namespaces are consistent jsf 2.2+ ones and not a mix

Comment: My bad, I added `comp:myTooltip` now. @Kukeltje: not sure what you meant, do I have some wrong prefix there?